# how to map nested array within a mapped array in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

**TLDR:How would i better map an array within a initalState prop**

The following code im trying to attempt is to retrieve all `postIds` from the like array, and compare `post.id` to `like.postId`

However

> `like.postId` is undefined.

post.id is available on the console log, the difference between posts, and likes is that posts are mapped on the client side, and **likes are not**. So im trying to do the mapping in the reducer because i would need to get amount of like counts **stored for each post**, and map it to its respected post.id.

The reason why i would need to set the values within the likes initialState is because i would need to use this following action to upvote posts

```
  case ADD_LIKE:
        // console.log(action.id) // renders post id which is 2
        // console.log(state.posts) // logs posts array
        // console.log(state.posts)
            return {
            ...state,
            likes: state.likes + 1
        };
```

if i do something like this `like[0].postId` it will only get the values for that like.id only. I need to be able to get all of likes from all posts, and compare `like.postId` to `post.id` and then set the value.

And retrieve the count like

`{this.props.likes}`

just to get an idea what the array looks like.

This is example posts array, and within the Posts array, you have the likes array.

[image]

Here is how im calling posts

```
export const GetPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data
                 const likes = res.data // gets  the first item within array, and shows likes.
                 const myLikes = likes.map( (post) => {
                    return post.Likes
                 })
                 console.log(myLikes)

                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data, myLikes})
             })

    }
}
```

**reducer**

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
     case GET_POSTS:
            console.log(action.data[0].Likes.length)
            return {
                ...state, 
                posts: action.data, // maps posts fine
                // set likes to but it only gets the first post, when it should get all posts
                likes: action.data.map( (post) => {
                    action.myLikes.map( (like) => {
                        // if(post.id === like.postId){
                            console.log(like) // renders an array of likes for all posts
                            console.log(like.postId) // renders undefined, 
                        // }
                    })
                })
        }
}
```

this is how its being mapped

**PostList.js**

```
render(){
        const {posts} = this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                {posts.map((post, i) => (
                    <Paper key={post.id} style={Styles.myPaper}>

                    {/* {...post} prevents us from writing all of the properties out */}
                        <PostItem                     
                             myTitle={this.state.title} 
                             editChange={this.onChange} 
                             editForm={this.formEditing} 
                             isEditing={this.props.isEditingId === post.id} 
                             removePost={this.removePost} 
                             {...post} 
                        />
                    </Paper>
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

GetPosts action is called within this component

```
class Posts extends Component {
  state = {
    posts: [],
    loading: true,
    isEditing: false, 
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    await this.props.GetPosts();
    this.setState({ loading: false })
    const reduxPosts = this.props.myPosts;
    const ourPosts = reduxPosts  
    console.log(reduxPosts); // shows posts line 35
  }

  render() {
    const {loading} = this.state;
    const { myPosts} = this.props
    if (!this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      return (<Redirect to='/signIn' />);
    }
    if(loading){
      return "loading..."
    }
    return (
      <div className="App" style={Styles.wrapper}>
        <h1> Posts </h1>
        <PostList posts={myPosts}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.user.isAuthenticated,
  myPosts: state.post.posts
})
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, state) => ({
  GetPosts: () => dispatch( GetPosts())
});
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Posts));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it will **create a new array** with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array, so you will get an array of arrays (array of each post's likes array) in order to solve your issue and get an array of likes you need to use the reducer function as follows:

```
export const GetPosts = () => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
        .then( (res) => {
             const data = res.data
             const likes = res.data // gets  the first item within array, and shows likes.
             const myLikes = likes.reduce( (acc,post) => {
                    return acc.concat(post.Likes)
                 },[])
             console.log(myLikes)

             dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data, myLikes})
         })
}}
```

Comment: what about the reducer ? should i just call it like `likes: action.myLikes`. thank you so much for this, been stressing out over this. your explanation makes sense, im about to try this out.

Comment: how would i be able to store the values of likes. for example post 1 has 39 likes, and post 2 has 100 likes, etc. How would i be able to store like counts, and have it mapped to the corresponding post.id. I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: its just setting all like values to value of the first post. when it should be mapped to a specific post id